# Nesting Product in AggregateRating

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

Our site is a review site, not a shop. We have 'product description' pages that list product information with a bunch of user reviews. At the top you can see the product, its price, and the aggregate score.

I think this page is fundamentally an `AggregateRating` type, right? But it also has a bunch of data relevant to product, brand, offers, etc.

How do you think I should structure this? Here's what I was thinking for the general layout:

```html
<li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        <span itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"> 
            <img itemprop="image">  
            <b itemprop="name"></b>
            <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PriceSpecification">
                <em itemprop="price" priceCurrency="USD"></em>
            </span>
        </span> <!-- Product itemscope end -->
        <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5"> <!-- set range of possible ratings -->
        <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="0">
        <span itemprop="ratingValue"></span>
        <span itemprop="reviewCount"></span>
    </span> 
</li>
```

Schema.org only shows examples of `AggregateRating` nested inside of other data -- is it incorrect to use it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s what the [`itemReviewed`](http://schema.org/itemReviewed) property is for, so yes, nesting it like that is fine.

Note that nesting items in other items doesn’t connect them, unless you use a property. So your `PriceSpecification` is standing on its own, it’s not related to the `Product` in any way.

If you want to provide the price(s) of a product, you have to provide [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer) items (or an [`AggregateOffer`](http://schema.org/AggregateOffer)). Use the [`offers`](http://schema.org/offers) property for this.

(Also, the `em` element can’t have a `priceCurrency` attribute.)

So the structure could be:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">

  <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateOffer"> <!-- or omit this "AggregateOffer" if you don’t want to provide e.g. a "lowPrice" -->

      <ul>
        <li itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"></li>
        <li itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"></li>
        <li itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the `Product` is connected to the `AggregateReview` because it has both the `itemReviewed` and the `itemscope` markup. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: @DanielThompson: `itemscope` creates the item (and `itemtype` gives this item a type). Only `itemprop` connects items. So without `itemprop`, you would have two stand-alone / top-level items, an `AggregateRating` and a `Product`, not connected/related. With the `itemReviewed` property, you convey: this `AggregateRating` is for this `Product`.

Comment: Wow I had no idea appreciate the info!